# Error when compiling website but not when building

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a website solution which includes a website project, a data layer project and an entities project.

When I build and run the website, I have no issues. However when I compile (with precompiling) I get errors.

The errors I get are all from one page:

```
Error   36  'branches_list' is not a member of 'users'. 
Error   37  'cash_seq' is not a member of 'users'.  
Error   38  'management_seq' is not a member of 'users'.    
Error   39  'Password' is not a member of 'users'.
```

The full error is:

```
error BC30456: 'management_seq' is not a member of 'users'.
```

The list includes all attributes of the users class which is found in the entities project. 
There are other pages on the site which use the same class which don't generate any errors.

Everything is being referenced correctly, the same .NET version is being used on all projects.

I've included a bit of the code and the class below:

```
Dim _user As New Users

_user.Password = txtPassword.Text


Public Class Users

    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property isAdmin As Boolean
    Public Property isActive As Boolean
    Public Property management_seq As String
    Public Property cash_seq As String
    Public Property stock_seq As String
    Public Property customers_seq As String
    Public Property suppliers_seq As String
    Public Property graphs_seq As String
    Public Property additional_seq As String
    Public Property branches_list As List(Of Branches)

End Class

Public Class Branches

    Public Property BranchCode

End Class
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `*.dll.refresh` for each reference in web site bin folder?

Comment: Yes, but not on the DLL for the data layer and entities projects.

Comment: So, here what you need to do for successful precompile - add all your DLLs directly to BIN and if this still not working - in web.config under `<compilation><assemblies>` add this `<add assembly="my.assembly.Name">`. Make sure not to type `.dll` in the end

Comment: Your problem is - when you build in solution - its sucks in all the references. And when you precompile, the dependencies are not there. You have to physically place them into bin. Most likely scenario is create a batch file that will collect your DLLs into web/bin and fire aspnet_compiler.exe

Comment: So why would I not have an issue on the other pages? So I should add as <add assembly="my.assembly.Entities"/> where Entities is the name of my Entities project?

Comment: Yes. First try just to place assemblies into bin manually and pre-compile. I've seen this today. I added `<remove assembly="my.assembly">` and my global.asax stopped finding namespaces. At compile time of precompilation.  But at runtime, if I don't add this line, I would have problem when asp.net trying to do runtime compile.In my case, my assembly is obfuscated and this is why I have to deal with it this way. So, when I build web site, I use non-obfuscated assembly. Just an example of how it works. Yes, you sometimes, for indirect references need this for precompillation

Comment: The DLLs get created during the publish. I can see them being created. I tried your suggestions but they're not working :(

Comment: Sorry, but DLLs do not get created during publish. Aspnet_compiler.exe builds each page into a DLL while uses DLLs in Bin folder for reference. Do you use in-place compilation? As a build master, I do this 20+ times a day. Not manually of course but I run scripts that do it. In my script, I totally clear out web/bin folder, then copy into it all the DLLs that web app uses, then build it using separate `targetDir`. Your problem is that namespaces are not found. It tells that during compilation aspnet doesn't have your assembly loaded into app domain.  You need to force it in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89275/discussion-between-daniel-gee-and-t-s).